# Polyfill (kindof) for const?

Tags: javascript, constants, arrow-functions, let

Actually I am dealing with the problem to let my code work in IE. Unfortunately this is still necessary.

Polyfills for unsupported methods are working fine. 
But I wonder, how / if I can make "const" and "let" work. Is there any way to do that?

Same question about arrow-functions which may be much harder.

Best regards, Christian

Comment: I don't think you can create polyfil for **keywords** or **reserved words**.

Comment: You may find it better to transpile your code, if possible.

Comment: No, if you have to support IE, than you need to use something like babel in your build process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't *polyfill* syntax changes to the language. But you can *transpile* your code that uses new syntax into code that uses older syntax, using tools like [Babel](https://babeljs.io) or [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler), and then run that generated older-style code on IE. They compile (or "transpile") code written with, say, ES2015+ features into code written with only ES5-level features (usually combined with polyfills).

For example, this code using an arrow function:

```
Nifty.prototype.setupHandler = function() {
    this.element.addEventHandler("click", e => {
        ++this.clicks;
    });
};
```

is transpiled by Babel into:

```
Nifty.prototype.setupHandler = function () {
    var _this = this;

    this.element.addEventHandler("click", function (e) {
        ++_this.clicks;
    });
};
```

[Example](http://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAORsKBPAFAUwDY4C2OYUAlIgN4BQiiUAFjAM4B0-RJUiAvIh8VIBuWvSZsIeGBADWzXogAMIgL7VU6DKwAOAJzhQDGbTlbMcUENoASAQzAATAroWhIsBFgo06dRi3YCQShWWwcHAFEANy47R2csACJJaRlEgBp-XgA-KlFfXwBqQv8JKVlmEQKVMlUhIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)

Comment: Thank you, I expected that but I hoped for something unexpected ;)